# what does the writeToFile service do in webmethods?

Tags: webmethods

*

> **Can any one explain me the writeToFile service do in webMethods**

*

Comment: Can you add more info? I do not have such service in wM 9.8... What is the full name of the service (with package).

Comment: Same as @Betlista, I don't have writeToFile service in vanilla webMethods. Do you have third party packages installed ?

Comment: Almost a week later and not reply - voting to close it.

Answer (score 1):

In webMethods out-of-the-box there is no such service.
There is a service PSUtilities.file:writeToFile commonly used by people from PSUtilities2_x package. It us used to write a string into a file (like name actually suggests).

It requires three input parameters:

userData - actual string to write to file

filename - complete file path (folder+file name)

appendOverwriteFlag - flag indicating whether to overwrite file contents or append string to to end of the existing file

**Update:** in newer wM versions (checked 9.9+ versions) there are new services:

- pub.file:readerToFile
- pub.file:streamToFile
- pub.file:stringToFile

that can be used to wrote content to file. Please refer to available document ation in "Integration_Server_Built_In_Services_Reference" document for more details on service usage.